# Skype snap won't connect

Tags: skype, proxy, snap

I just installed Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 as a snap package. Skype will start but it won't connect, giving me a network error. I'm behind a proxy server. How can I make Skype recognize my proxy server?

I have the correct proxy setting under `/etc/environment`, and the Slack snap is working just fine, so it seems that it's a problem with the Skype snap.

Comment: Same issue on 18.04: Skype snap won't connect when behind a proxy.